# LaTeX: Insert within document a Unicode Character which is not contained in the font

Tags: xetex, unicode

I try to insert a Unicode Character `\char"2756` (Black Diamond Minus White X) which is not contained in the font `newcomputermodern`

I need this as a paragraph separator.

So my question:

1. how to change the font inside the document
2. how to find this character in a LaTeX font - is it contained or not? Trial and error? Or is there a cleverer means to find it; for example in the command line?

Just to complete my question: I am writing texts in markdown with parts of LaTeX inserted. Compiling with XeTeX.

Thank you for your help

marek

Comment: "how to find this character in a font" -> have a look at the albatross command line tool. It will search all fonts you have installed on your operating system for this symbol.

Comment: you can use `albatross U+2756` on a command line to get a list of fonts, then use the fontspec command to load and use it, see the fontspec docu.

Comment: Thank you both for the `albatross` suggestion. Very useful. And how to change the font inside the document?

Comment: To make albatross working I needed to install java first. Now it is working! Amazing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `newunicodechar` and defining a font face that contains the symbol.

Or you can use the standard Zapf Dingbats Type 1 font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontsetup} % NewComputerModern
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontface{\auxfontA}{DejaVu Sans}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newunicodechar{❖}{{\auxfontA ❖}}
\newcommand{\bdmwx}{❖}

\begin{document}

Some text ❖ other text \bdmwx\ other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

With Zapf Dingbats

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontsetup} % NewComputerModern
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newunicodechar{❖}{{\Pifont{pzd}\symbol{118}}}
\newcommand{\bdmwx}{❖}

\begin{document}

Some text ❖ other text \bdmwx\ other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg. Working!